# In Amazon S3, what permissions do I need to get HEAD on an object?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-s3, head

I'm trying to get HEAD on an object, and I'm getting 403 forbidden. What permissions do I need to, in order to get HEAD on the object, using the REST API?

I have the code in place to get the full object contents using a signed URL... but when I switch to get HEAD instead of getting the full object, it gives me the 403 forbidden

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the same permission as for GET. If you can get an object, you can do a HEAD request on it. But you can't use the same signed URL for HEAD and GET because the request method is used to compute the signature, so they will have different signatures. Create a new signed URL for the HEAD request and it should work.

Comment: that was it! thanks, yo. the code I was using (the Knox.js library) hides the default "GET" verb in the signing, but makes it easy to override. once i added the override to grant permission for HEAD, it worked.

Comment: @DerickBailey How did you grant permission for HEAD?